# Vue3 How to re-render the app on a second device when changing pinia store in the first?

Tags: vuejs3, cross-browser, pinia

My problem is on a user settings when he change his informations (like language, name, address...).
For example, I open my project on two different browser. If I change default language from english to french in one browser it's OK, the default language is well setting on store and it display well on screen, but the second windows in another browser still in english and the store still have 'english' for default language too. Do you know why? And how to fix it?

I tried to add a 'watch' function but it's unsuccessfull

Answer (score 1):

Pinia stores are not a database that can be accessed by other instances of the same site by default. Two different tabs will have two different states. There are plugins out there that can sync state across tabs, but I don't think they exist for different windows and definitely not different browsers.

If you want data to persist no matter what device, browser, or tab the user is accessing the site from, you'll need to store the data in a database somewhere. Once you do that, you can subscribe to the data you need and receive updates when it's changed across any open version of the page.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is not on persist datas but more on refresh the page on change in another browser (or typically on native/web app page) with the persisted datas. I saw some plugins but none I can use with yarn.. I tried to refresh the page each time I do a change but it's not the interest of a front language..